# get application name from package name

Tags: android

I want to get the application name from application package name.  Somebody please show me how I can get this.

```
public class AppInstalledListener extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED")){
            Logger.debug("DATA:"+intent.getData().toString());
        }
        if(action.equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")){
            Logger.debug("DATA:"+intent.getData().toString());
        }
        if(action.equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED")){
            Logger.debug("DATA:"+intent.getData().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 219):

You can use `PackageManager` class to obtain `ApplicationInfo`:

```
final PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo ai;
try {
    ai = pm.getApplicationInfo( this.getPackageName(), 0);
} catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
    ai = null;
}
final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
```

This would return the application name as defined in `<application>` tag of its manifest.

Comment: that's perfect. Been looking for it for hours, thanks Xion. :D

Comment: its returning me unknown all the time i alrady have package name just want to know name from package name

Comment: This is not working when i use this in the global receiver

Comment: you cannot get applicationInfo of a package after PACKAGE_REMOVED.

Comment: perfect one.. just copy paste.. gets the work done. thank you.

Comment: This logic will not work in Android 11 onwards, You need to have permissions. Did anyone find any other way to handle this?

Comment: [Be carefull as you will need to use `<queries>` in manifest for Android 11 (API 30) onwards.](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) If you want to query about any package, you can instead use the permission `android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES`.

Answer (score 46):

Try this

```
final String packageName = "my.application.package"
PackageManager packageManager= getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
String appName = (String) packageManager.getApplicationLabel(packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
```

> and replace `packageName` with your package full name.

you can get **packageName** using `mContext.getPackageName()` where `mContext = yourActivityName.this` for Activity and **getActivity() for fragment.**

Answer (score 22):

```
 public static String getAppNameFromPkgName(Context context, String Packagename) {
    try {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        ApplicationInfo info = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(Packagename, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        String appName = (String) packageManager.getApplicationLabel(info);
        return appName;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are able to receive the event of new package added after that its a very simple concept to get the all relevant information about that package like one such information is the application name so here is the concept

-> your device package manager has all the information related to it so just make an object of that it will give you all the information related with the package name.

-> You should also remember that the intent gives you "package: real_package_name" so first you have to get real name first by spilling(I used) or by any other simple implementation of String

-> Here is the code hope you will get what you want I m also giving information about how you can get app name,app icon,app version,app version code etc.....

```
    public class NewAppReciver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED")){
    String[] a=intent.getData().toString().split(":");
    String packageName=a[a.length-1];

    List<PackageInfo> packageInfoList =          context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < packageInfoList.size(); i++) {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = packageInfoList.get(i);
        if(packageInfo.packageName.equals(packageName)){
            String appName = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()).toString();
            String appVersion = packageInfo.versionName;
            int appVerCode = packageInfo.versionCode;
            Drawable app_icon = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager());
             }
         }
      }
   }    
}
```

But at the time of the application Uninstall you can only get the package name as on Un installation all other information gets removed by the system.

Comment: intent.getData().toString() is not the way to go, the data in the intent is structured.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below, it worked for me.

```
public static ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> getLaunchableInstalledApps(Context context){

    final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo:pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)){
        try {
            ApplicationInfo app = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, 0);
            list.add(app);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (cacheAppsList.isEmpty()){
        cacheAppsList.addAll(list);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
filter.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
filter.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

Context context = getApplicationContext();
ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), TestReplaceHomeAppActivity.class.getName());

ComponentName[] components = new ComponentName[] {new ComponentName("com.android.launcher", "com.android.launcher.Launcher"), component};

pm.clearPackagePreferredActivities("com.android.launcher");
pm.addPreferredActivity(filter, IntentFilter.MATCH_CATEGORY_EMPTY, components, component);
```