# context.getApplicationInfo().name is always null

Tags: android, null, android-context

This line always returns null.  In this particular case the context is an activity.  Any ideas are very much appreciated!

**Edit**

```
context.getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().name
```

Still returns null

Comment: I think that you would need to `getApplicationInfo()` on the Application Context

Answer (score 1):

Look at [get application name from package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841161/get-application-name-from-package-name) for the answer. The highest rated entry there worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In order to read `android:name` attribute in  tag, you have to access `ApplicationInfo.className` field instead. Thus,

```
context.getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().className
```

will return what you expect.

Comment: Sorry, but that returns null also.

Comment: Does official documentation/code state this anywhere?