# Android `applicationInfo.name` is always null on Android API <= 24

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-applicationinfo

I am working on an Android library and want to programmatically access the `android:name` attribute of the `<application>` tag from the Manifest file. According to official documentation, this is the correct way to get the `android:name` attribute.

```
myApp.applicationInfo.name //myApp is the instance of my custom Application subclass
```

This works fine on devices with Android API > 24. But if I use a device running Android API below that, it returns null.

PS 1: I am not interested in the application label as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021966/packagemanagers-applicationinfo-name-is-always-null).

PS 2: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12499201/5493999) suggests that we use `applicationInfo.className` instead, but I cannot find any official documentation/code sample which clearly states this.

Comment: When do you read the name field from your application class, before onCreate is called or after?

Comment: In `onCreate` of my custom application subclass, after the `super.onCreate` is called.