# Get app name from package name in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop an android app that could list all app's which has cache, I successfully got the information about cache, but now I want to display those app which has some cache in the screen, I have the package name, but problem is how to get the application name from package name,

Let's say package name is `com.android.browser`
then app name will be `Browser`

How to achieve this task ?

Please don't mind if this question is silly to you, please help me in solving this riddle,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get application name from package name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841161/get-application-name-from-package-name)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use `PackageManager` to get detailed information about installed packages.

```
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = null;
try {
    applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
} catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {}
final String title = (String)((applicationInfo != null) ? packageManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo) : "???");
```

Comment: In the first approach `getApplicationName` you passed Context as parameter, but actually I want to get name of other app from my app, that means Context will be different right, then if we execute `int stringId = context.getApplicationInfo().labelRes;` we will get our present app `id`

Comment: Oh you removed first approach ?

Comment: I did as it was not answering your question

Comment: Ok Thanks @Marcin Orlowski for your time. But unfortunately this approach is not working.

Comment: what is not working? This will return application name (label) as set in app manifest

Comment: `context` is not defined. If I use getApplicationContext() then again it will not work

Comment: Thanks @Marcin Orlowsk,your code is working. I made a little modification as for my app requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `PackageManager#getActivityInfo();`
There is field which contain app name.

Comment: How do you initialse PackageManager to your defined package name, let's say `com.android.browser` how will you initialse `PackageManager` to our own package @adek