# How to add label below GridView item Android?

Tags: android, gridview, textview, launcher

Right now I'm working on a launcher app, in which I've made a `GridView` which fetches all installed apps from the device. But there are only app icons and no app names. And I wanted to put app name below it so I tried to put `TextView` below my app icon `ImageView`, but my app crashes. Any ideas how should I fix it? Here's my code: Thank you very much!

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView i;

            if (convertView == null) {
                i = new ImageView(Apps.this);
                i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                i.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(93, 93));
                i.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);


            } else {
                i = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            ResolveInfo info = mApps.get(position);
            i.setImageDrawable(info.activityInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager()));

            return i;
        }
```

Comment: Oh I see! Can you show me an example please?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building a `view` that contain `TextView` and `ImageView`, use `CompoundDrawable`. You only have to implement one `TextView` and set it's `DrawableTop` with the required icon. This will do the job.

From the XML file

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_textview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/my_icon"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

Or you can do it programmatically using the following:

```
myTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, topDrawable, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a TextView as the image container, by using a **compound drawable**: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)

So, you'll set `1 View to replace 2 ones`, with **UI simplification** and **performance improvements**, as side-effects.

A little example:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView t;

        if (convertView == null) {
            t = new TextView(Apps.this);
            t.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(93, 93));
            t.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);

            ResolveInfo info = mApps.get(position);
            Drawable drw = info.activityInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());

            t.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, drw, null, null);
            //t.setText("Some Text");
            t.setText(info.activityInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString());

        } else {
            t = (TextView) convertView;
        }

        return t;
    }
```

**[EDIT]**

Once you return the View (t, the TextView), you can get the drawable by using `getCompoundDrawables()`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getCompoundDrawables()

Comment: Every line of code is fine except that `info`, I'm getting error at that line, any solution?

Comment: Sorry, I messed up some code, while refactoring. Fixed.

Comment: But I have to already return i; for the icon ImageView, then how to return two things at a time? Any way to achieve it?

Comment: You return the View (t, the TextView). Then you can get the drawable by using `getCompoundDrawables()`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getCompoundDrawables()

Comment: Hey bro I used the code you mentioned above, but it is showing only app icons in Grid and no TextView, why so?

Comment: This `t.setText("Some Text");` has to be changed to the app names. Something like: `t.setText(info.activityInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()));`

Comment: I forgot to add `.toString()`. Updated

Comment: Unfortunately this is too not working :( I tried it.

Comment: I guess [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17489988/2649012) from @MarcinOrlowski can help.