# build a custom Share dialog as in Marshmallow

Tags: android

How to get the application label from ApplicaitonInfo class in android.
I need to get application label as in default share dialog that we get in Marshmallow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489781/get-app-name-from-package-name-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The share dialog get the labels from the `ResolveInfo` object [LINK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html).

It get those objects by calling:

```
List<ResolveInfo> targets = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(targetIntent, 0);
```

in the `ResolveInfo` you can get the label using:

```
resolveInfo.loadLabel(packageManager);
```

Comment: I was using packageManager.getApplciationInfo to get applciation name which was not providing Tweet and Direct Message,It was providing Only Twitter itself.Your piece of code works fine.

Comment: @AnandDR ApplicationInfo have info about "everything inside the APK together". ResolveInfo gives you a direct intent, which one application can have more than one intent-filter that match your share requirements.