# How to get Application name from package name in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which if any app is installed in device I have to update to server with app name for that I have to get Application name from package name.

for example :- from package let suppose :- `<com.example.Deals>` from this I have to get only `<Deals>`. How can I do that.

here is my code from which I got package name using Broadcast receiver.

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action.equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED")){
        Logger.debug("DATA:"+intent.getData().toString());
    }
    if(action.equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")){
        Logger.debug("DATA:"+intent.getData().toString());
    }
    if(action.equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED")){
        Logger.debug("DATA:"+intent.getData().toString());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get application name from package name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841161/get-application-name-from-package-name)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get Application name from package using following code

```
final PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo ai;
try {
    ai = pm.getApplicationInfo( "your_package_name", 0);
} catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
    ai = null;
}
final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 PackageManager packageManagers= getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        try {
            String appName = (String) packageManagers.getApplicationLabel(packageManagers.getApplicationInfo("com.example.packagename", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here dont miss to change your package name `com.example.packagename`

Answer (score 0):

check following code

```
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo applicationInfo;
try {
    applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
} catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {}
final String title = (String)((applicationInfo != null) ? packageManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo) : "???");
```