# How to get app name by package name in android?

Tags: android, package, apk, aapt

I am writing a command line tool to get app name by package name, and trying the following ways.

1. **PackageManager** in android API provide the function, but mine tool is not an APK, thus there's no Context.
2. command **AAPT** can parse app name from apk, `adb shell aapt dump badging /data/app/com.google.android.apps.inbox-1/base.apk`, but my device has no aapt, I downloaded one from [here](https://android.izzysoft.de/downloads), it complains "error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported".

any helps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841161/get-application-name-from-package-name

Answer (score 1):

To get App Name try this. It would provide the application name which is defined in  tag of app's manifest.

```
PackageManager packageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo ;
    try {
        applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo( this.getPackageName(), 0);
    } catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
        applicationInfo = null;
    }
    String applicationName = (String) (applicationInfo != null ? packageManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo ) : "(unknown)");
```

Comment: He cannot do that. He doesn't want to get app name in his android app. He is developing a cmd tool which can retrieve the name of app from package. He mentioned that in his question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AAPT2 command in linux to get the package name of an APK.

```
./aapt2 dump packagename <path_to_apk>
```

But you need to download newer versions of AAPT2 from here:
[Download AAPT from Google Maven](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2#download_aapt2)

You can try this executing this command in a shell script, so that you will be able to use the package name.

PS: I used AAPT2 version 3.3.0-5013011 for testing the above command.