# How to get the Mainactivity name of other apps in my app, as a parameter of ComponentName

Tags: android

Im writing an android application that gets list of all system and installed apps, and if user checks the particular app then that app has to hide from launcher, for hiding the ComponentName of that app is required, I can get the package name but how to get the activity/class name of other apps.
How to make such an app for nonrooted mobile.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using Androids [**`PackageManager.getApplicationLabel()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getApplicationLabel(android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo))

For an example see this Answer: 
[get application name from package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841161/get-application-name-from-package-name)

Comment: getting application name and mainactivity name are two different things If im not wrong

Comment: True. I don't know what you really need. Within the PackageManager you find methods to query for the ApplicationInfo as well as ActivityInfo(s). If it is not there, I am afraid there is no way for non-rooted phones to get info about apps (running in another sandbox).

Comment: yes sir, I agree about the apps run in separate sandbox, but there r apps that can hide icons in launcher that work with non rooted mobiles. @ r-hold

Comment: I got the solution for this sir.                                                                                                                    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager(); Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);  List<ResolveInfo> appList = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);  Collections.sort(appList, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));
 for (ResolveInfo temp : appList) {
 Log.v("my logs", "package and activity name = " +temp.activityInfo.packageName + " + temp.activityInfo.name);}